# Change flutter version path from github to current sdk path

Tags: android, git, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm relatively new to flutter development, and I'm having some difficulties. I recently created a project with flutter and it was working fine until I had to update the flutter SDK which I did using the git clone...but along the way, I found out that the git clone was giving me some problems so I decided to download the current flutter SDK version 1.17.5 and add the path to my environment variables and delete that git folder.

After trials and errors, I was able to delete the files inside the flutter folder but the folder just won't go away... so I kinda ignored it, thinking it wouldn't disturb me but well, I dunno it kinda came back

What I mean by that is, when I created a new project with the new SDK path of flutter which is already in my environment variables..I'm still having troubles with the app because I copied the code from my previous project and pasted it in this new project and made the necessary changes it needed. But when it gets to the stage of installing the apk..it freezes..literally!

I thought it was something I did, so I did my best trying to solve it but it's not working..and when I try to click on the app in my device (note: I am not using an emulator, I am using my device which is Tecno Spark 4)...it tells me that unfortunately, the app has stopped...

and when I checked the version it's telling that the current SDK it is using is the one from git clone!
but my text editor which is VS Code is not using that SDK! It is rather using the one from the path that I set in the environment variables!

here is what flutter version told me:

```
Flutter 1.17.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
```

Comment: You can use logcat to catch the app's crash log

Comment: I tried doing that, but my logcat won't even show me anything it just keeps saying **please configure android sdk**

Comment: You should configure the android sdk so you can get the crash logs

Comment: hmmm, ok lemme try that...thanks for the help!!!

Comment: run `flutter doctor -v` and post it here

Comment: It worked!!!, thank you so much @JideGuru !....after configuring the android SDK I was able to see the mistake I made in the package name...when I fixed It, It started working!!! really appreciate your help, God bless you!

Comment: You're welcome @CharisaEmmanuel

Comment: Thank you too @Ride Sun , just found out that it was my mistake....but really I appreciate your help too!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it with getting a report from the logcat in Android Studio...but in case this doesn't work for you just open the android module in a different window in Android Studio **by going to `logcat` then click on the link that says `configure` SDK and an alert dialog will pop up asking you if you would like to open it in a different window or the current window: choose `Open in New Window`** and let it build the Gradle to get the required plugins and all..then it should work